# fastest format for giant vector image

Tags: canvas, dictionary, svg, html5-canvas

I want to display a static worldmap with some countries colored stretching pagewide (width 100%) in modern browsers.
Similar to this map, but without the interaction.
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#geo_chart

What would get me this with the smallest filesize, or more importantly fastest load time.
An SVG, optimized PNG (as big as biggest screensize), or html5 canvas, or other (no flash)?
Of course I could use the google geochart, filesize is not important since I don't host it, but loadtime might be slower, and also limited to n loads per hour or day?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is try my SVG converter. It will try to convert your map SVG into 3 formats of javascript/HTML. There are 2 Raphael and 1 jQuery SVG formats that it can currently produce (V0.7)
Then compare the load time of all 3 formats.

http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/SVGTOHTML_LIVE.php

Comment: Is the resulting output html5 canvas? I believe that's lighter then svg in filesize.